# How to create Django model with FK field based on ID from URL of post request?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am making a simple API in DjangoRESTFramework. I have following model of a task, that belongs to one and only one Educational application (eduapp for short):

```py
class Task(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    eduapp = models.ForeignKey(EduApp, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

and simple serializer for it:

```py
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    taskId = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('taskId', 'name')
```

To access these tasks, I have a view that shows list of all tasks with given eduapp id (eduapp is another model). Eduapp id is taken from URL used for requests with following url pattern: `path('eduapps/<int:eduapp_id>/tasks/', views.TaskList.as_view()),` so for example:

`localhost:8000/eduapps/1/tasks/` gives my view eduapp id of 1:

```py
class TaskList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Task.objects.all()
        eduapp_id = self.kwargs.get('eduapp_id')
        queryset = queryset.filter(eduapp=eduapp_id)
        return queryset
```

This works just fine. However, I am now at the point where I want to also save new tasks (previously injected straight into DB) and not just list existing ones.
I am wondering how to propagate eduapp_id from the view into serializer, and how to then utilize it as a foreign key for new eduapp field (which already exists in model), something along the lines of:

```py
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    taskId = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', required=False)

    eduapp = ??? some magic ???

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('taskId', 'name', 'eduapp')   # new field name here
```

So far, I've tried defining my own create function in serializer and setting FK there:

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = Task.objects.create(**validated_data)
        instance.eduapp = EduApp.objects.get(id=1)
        return instance
```

here with hardcoded eduapp id of 1. This seemed to work sort of okay, but made it so that POSTs still required body to include value of `eduapp`. To counter that, I included this in serializer:

```py
    eduapp = EduAppSerializer(read_only=True,
                                many=False,
                                allow_null=True)
```

which I don't really like because, while it makes `eduapp` no longer required on POSTs, I had no intention of actually displaying the eduapp portion when deserializing on GETs (I can live with that though).

However, I wasn't able to get past the hardcoded value in my create() function. I've found some tidbits about setting custom contexts in view (where I can access  and then reaching into them while in serializer, but it just seems like a massive overkill for issue which I think is quite common and that should hopefully have premade solution I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You would associate a specific route from your specific `EduApp` or pass it in the payload.

The route `/eduapp/10/tasks` could be used to create a specific `Task` while at the same time it has information about the `eduapp_id` to help you locate the unique instance you want to associate it with.

So now you could do a lookup of :

```
instance.eduapp = EduApp.objects.get(id=eduapp_id)
```

assuming you named the paramater `eduapp_id`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer - I understand what you are saying conceptually and it is exactly my intention, but how do I actually get the eduapp_id into my serializer? I am talking down to code solution here.

Comment: @OndřejŠlejtr checkout the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/